# installing Centos 7 and configure RAID 10

Tags: centos, raid

I had a system with 4x500GB HDD and a 16GB pendrive. I would like to build a homeserver with RAID 10. Currently i use nas4free. But i am planning to setup a local file server as well as a webserver.

Is it possible to install centos 7 in a pendrive and use it as bootable and configure the hdd as a RAID10 array?

If one drive fails or the pendrive fail will be able recover others?

My plan is to install minimal centos7 and use webmin as system administration.

Comment: Why would you bother with the pendrive?  Just install on the raid array.

Comment: Actually i think it would be faster and also i can differentiate the os and space. But am not at all aware of the pros and cons of this system?

Comment: Faster at what?  Booting up?  If it's a sever that is just going to stay on then what does that matter?

Comment: currently am using na4free in the same setup. I had no idead whether it's good or bad .. :)

Comment: @psusi My primary intention was to if i need to upgrade the space i can replace it easily.. i think so.. still am not sure. Currently am using 500gb and if i replace it with 1 tb i think i can easily sitchthat.

Comment: What does that have to do with the pen drive?

Comment: if i install the os on a pendrive i think i can easily swap drives in future.

Comment: You can do that without the pen drive.